# Is it possible to add system time in Windows NumericUpDown Button control?

Tags: c#

I want to add current system time information into NumericUpDown Button control. Does this possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a **DateTimePicker** instead, setting its *Format* and *ShowUpDown* properties to achieve what you describe:

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

This will give you a control that looks and acts like a *NumericUpDown*, but with time instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

No. This control is only for numbers and datetime is not a number.

By default, the numeric UpDown displays natural numbers. Alternatively, you can make the numeric UpDown control display hexadecimal numbers. The type of numbers displayed is controlled by the Boolean Hexadecimal property whose default value is False, which means that it is primarily meant to display natural numbers. If you prefer the control to display hexadecimal numbers, set this property to True.

By default, the numeric UpDown control is made to display only natural numbers. If you want it to display decimal numbers, use the DecimalPlaces property to specify the number of decimal places on the right side of the decimal separator which, in US English, is the period.